# SQL Loop - Organize 3 dimensional data into 2 dimensional table

Tags: sql, dynamic, while-loop

I'm fairly fluent in VBA but only have only written rudimentary conditional select statements in SQL. I have a static table, STFile, that has roughly 900 columns. It snapshots a live table once a day, to create a history.

```
ST...Date….ST1_PROD…ST1_PCT 1…ST1_PCT 2…ST2_PROD…ST2_PCT 1…ST2_PCT 2…etc.
AA..3/5/14.141……...…..0.8………..…..0.2……...…..142……...…...0.95……..…..0.05……..…..
BB..3/5/14.010……....…..1……..…..…..0……......…..141……...…...0.8……..…....0.2……..…..
CC..3/5/14.141……...…..0.8………..…..0.2……...…..142……...…...0.95……….…..0.05……..…..
```

There are 35 different ST's, 120 products (010,141,etc), and 128 different column groups they might be in (collection of PROD, PCT 1, PCT 2, for each product).

What I did: a query that returns all info about one product in one column. I exported all 'PROD" columns and used VBA and excel to write a 1,000 line long brute force query using conditional when/then select statements.

The problem: the running table is subject to changes daily. If we delete prod 10 from BB, the column references shift for all following columns ST3_PROD-->ST2_PROD, ST2_PROD-->ST1_PROD, etc. Now, each column contains data about different products.

My first thought: brute force query. Check every appropriate column for value, for every product, for every ST. However, ST=35*Prod=120*Cols=128 == 540,000 lines of query, just to return prod name, let alone the whole group of data...

What I want: a loop that checks each column for the value, then returns that column if it finds the product name. If I had a functioning loop, I could simply create an array with my products, and have a dynamic query. Updating the list with new products would be as simple as adding the product into the array!

So...any help?

P.S. sorry about the data table. My first posting = can't post images! Columns separated by periods.

Comment: It sounds like you have a table with 900 columns where each column corresponds to a product. The usual arrangement would be to have a “Products” table where each row represents an individual product and each column represents some attribute of the products (e.g. EPC, description, price, etc.). You also seem to assume that readers understand the unique context of your problem domain and know what you're talking about. You might get more interest with a generic example that everyone can understand.

Comment: One way would be to run select * from xyz; on your table and get metadata information which would contain column names. That way your products can handle dynamic column alterations. I am not familiar with VBA, so can't really provide any code, but that would be the approach. As stated above better to manage products in a separate table by themselves.

Comment: @Emmet Thank you for the advice. I am used to VBA forums where specificity on individual problems is preferred. And you are absolutely right about how the product table SHOULD be organized, but I am not the database admin, just reporting off it.

Comment: I am learning that I just need to put in the time to learn SQL syntax, structure, and nuances. Thanks anyways forum attenders, maybe you'll hear more structured and sensible questions from me in two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish it with a while loop nested in a while loop nested in a cursor-for loop.

"It" is querying a table that has rigid and generic column names but data that can potentially be in different columns for a different date. It is essentially a 3 dimensional data storage packed into a 2 dimensional table. Since I cannot change the parent table itself, my query reorganizes the data into a usable and sensible format.

I first pull 1 day's worth of data into a temp table, so I'm only sifting through 900 columns by 36 rows of data (instead of tens of thousands of rows) which greatly reduces the query time. However it still take roughly 8-9 seconds to run. If there is a more efficient way to accomplish this, I'm all ears.

Here is the working fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31576